# building an sObject from a json string in VF page

Tags: visualforce, json, sobject

How can I deserialize a JSON string into an sObject in a VF page?
I don't want to use a controller so I'm looking for the right approach to do this on the client side only.
Any ideas?

Comment: [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) is available in modern browsers. Is that sufficient? Why the "into an sObject" in the question?

Comment: I want to insert it to the database using sforce.conection.insert()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the JSON string has names that exactly match the SObject field names then you can use code like this:

```
var s = '{"Field1__c" : "Hello", "Field2__c": "World"}';
var o = JSON.parse(s);
var sob = new sforce.SObject('YourSObjectType__c');
for (var key in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        sob[key] = o[key];
    }
}
var result = sforce.connection.insert([sob]);
```

If the names do not match, instead of the loop you will need a series of assignments:

```
sob.Field1__c = o.JsonName1;
sob.Field2__c = o.JsonName2;
...
```

Comment: thanks, one question: is your iterating over (key in o(, is there any case where  o.hasOwnProperty(key) is false?

Comment: @Dedo Probably not in this case as I think JSON.parse creates a simple object with no prototype (though to be sure you would need to research or test against all browsers). Personally I'd leave it in.

Answer (score -3):

You have create a wrapper as per the Json string format and then You can deserialize it .

Comment: Please elaborate your answer. It is not helpful in its current form. Please describe what you mean by wrapper and where the deserialization should take place.